# fscaning a input file into a binary tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm so confused on how to do this. I guess my main problem is actually opening the file with command line arguments yet implementing the `add_to_tree` function from said file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int num;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
}node;

node* add_to_tree(node* head, int number);
void print_in_order(node* head);
void print_in_reverse(node* head);
void free_tree(node* head);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    node* head=NULL;
    int number;
    char* input;
    if(argc>2 || argc<2){
        printf("\nCorrect Usage: ./a.out <input file>\n");
    }
    node* tree=add_to_tree(head, number);
    print_in_order(tree);
    return 0;
}

node* add_to_tree(node* head, int number)
{
    char* input=argv[1];
    FILE *cfptr=fopen(input, "r");
    if(cfptr==NULL) {
        printf("\nFIle could not be opened\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while(fscanf(cfptr, "%d", &number)!=EOF){

        if(head==NULL){
            head=malloc(sizeof(node));
            head->num=number;
            head->left=NULL;
            head->right=NULL;
        }
        else if(number< head->num){
            add_to_tree(head->left, number);
        }
        else if(number> head->num){
            add_to_tree(head->right, number);
        }
    }
    return head;
}

void print_in_order(node* head)
{
    if(head==NULL){
        return;
    }
    node* current=head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        printf("\n Temp=%d\n", current->num);
    }
}
```

I'm also stuck on how to print the tree in general (there is no next pointer in the structs so after my `printf` I cant do `current=current->next`).

Comment: you have to open your file _outside_ `add_to_tree` or you'll open it recursively. pass file pointer in `add_to_tree`. Open file in the main function.

Comment: Hello and welcome to structural recursion.

Comment: first of all, This code can't compile.

Comment: Suggestion on how to print the tree: recursion. Write a function which prints a node content, then calls itself to print the "left" member, and again for the "right" member. Call that function for the root node of the tree.